# MVC 4 Equivalent of Angular Filter By

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

In angular we can filter results client side based on a search bar text input. (I believe by using something called 'filter by' but I don't remember.) Is there an equivalent structure for this in MVC 4?

I understand I can write the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(i => i.Attribute)){

    ... //Print ordered items.

}
```

Every search I've looked at shows how to do this but by posting the attribute/property to the controller. I'm looking to do this dynamically client side only if possible.

Comment: `Where(p => ....)` can filter the result.

Comment: If you are looking to do this client side only, then MVC4 is not an issue.  Take a look at modifying an autocomplete style control.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks guys I appreciate the help.